# Removing lowest values from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Say I have this array of hashes:

```
[{:title => "Frankenstein", :edition => 1}, {:title => "Frankenstein", :edition => 2}, {:title => "Dracula", :edition => 1}, {:title => "Dracula", :edition => 2}, {:title => "Dracula", :edition => 3}]
```

Is there an elegant way in which I can strip this array of all old editions, keeping only the highest (most recent) ones?

```
[{:title => "Frankenstein", :edition => 2}, {:title => "Dracula", :edition => 3}]
```

Comment: Do you want to remove (only) the **lowest** values, which will leave you with all others, or all values **lower** (than the highest)?

Comment: All values lower than the highest. I tested the solution you gave below, exactly what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do it like this:

```
array.group_by{|h| h[:title]}.values.map{|a| a.max_by{|h| h[:edition]}}
# => [{:title=>"Frankenstein", :edition=>2}, {:title=>"Dracula", :edition=>3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the highest value of any edition of specific type using below code

```
array = [{:title => "Frankenstein", :edition => 1}, {:title => "Frankenstein", :edition => 2}, {:title => "Dracula", :edition => 1}, {:title => "Dracula", :edition => 2}, {:title => "Dracula", :edition => 3}]

array.select{|x| x[:title] == "Dracula"}.max_by{|x| x[:edition]}
```